# Running a Cumulative Average

Tags: average

I'd like to run a cumulative average and I'm wondering if my process is sound.

Here's a small dataset:

Row 1: $\frac{2\cdot 60}{58} = 2.07$

Row 2: $\frac{4\cdot 45}{44} = 4.09$,    $\frac{2.07+4.04}{2} = 3.07$

Row 3: $\frac{3\cdot 60}{60} = 3.00$ $\frac{2.07+2.05+3.00}{3} = 3.05$

Note, each step, may or may not have the same divider (ie. $45$ or $60$).

Comment: A more usual approach would be (2*60+5*45+3*60)/(58+44+60)=2.96

Comment: @user12049 thanks, I'll try that out. I think it will simplify how I get and process my numbers doing it in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more usual approach would be (2*60+5*45+3*60)/(58+44+60)=2.96.

There are alternatives like moving averages and exponential moving averages, but neither would seem suited to your data which appears to come in batches.